Android 11 - IMX8M - Default Audio Stream Routing to Lineout - SGTL5000
Platform: IMX8M Custom Board
OS: Android 11
Kernel: 5.10.9-678025-gbccc0b2805b7-dirty
Codec: SGTL5000
Problem: Default Sound Audio Output with Line-Out
Is this card necessary for lineout audio routing .jpg?
My problem is about changing the default Android stream value to lineout. I have successfully played a .wav file by using the tinyplay command. So, the codec is working correctly. But when I play an example video by using the gallery app, which is am start -n  com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity -d example.mp4, the video opened on my lvds screen, but I did not hear a voice from lineout. There is no sound. As you know, we should hear a voice while we are trying to change the alarm sound or notification sound. But there is no sound when I click a sound effect on settings. So, the problem is in Android's OS itself.
When I google about this, I saw that there is a conf file which is named audio_policy_configuration.xml, I have changed defaultOutputDevice to lineout as shown below.
<modules>
<module name="primary" halVersion="2.0">
<attachedDevices>
<item>Speaker</item>
<item>Built-In Mic</item>
<item>Line-Out</item>
</attachedDevices>
<defaultOutputDevice>Line-Out</defaultOutputDevice> 

So when I build according to this configuration and write the image into the SD card, if I am using a dcss-lvds image (which is not working as lineout), I do not see line routing by checking the dumpsys audio command. But when I do the same by using the hdmi image, dumsys audio log comes with line routing as I intended. I have realized that when there is a sound card which is named imx-audio-hdmi, audio routing will be working correctly. But in the dcss-lvds image, even if I have enabled imx-audio-hdmi in the .dts file, there is no sound card which is named imx-audio-hdmi, and audiorouting is not working. The audio service is giving an error in the logcat also, which I have attached.
Where is the problem? Is there any other configuration parameter except audio_policy_configuration.xml? Why must I have imx-audio-hdmi in Android to do this routing correctly?
Attached file zip contents explanations:
audio_policy_configuration.txt: My configuration
dmesg hdmi image .txt: Dmesg log for hdmi image
dumpsys audio_hdmi.txt: Audio service log for hdmi image
dmesg dcss-lvds image.txt: Dmesg for dcss-lvds image. There is no imx-audio-hdmi sound card.
dumpsys audio dcss-lvds.txt: audio service log for dcss lvds image. Check there is no routing as devices.
logcat grep Audio.txt: Logcat output for audio. There are several messages repeating itself.
I have tried changing the audio_policy_configuration.xml file and changing the lvds dtsi to enable the hdmi sound, but it did not help.
